# R - Converting comma separating values in a string to a 2D array

Tags: r, csv, multidimensional-array

Essentially I'm sending two comma-separated string args to my R script and want to write R code which converts them to a 1 or 2-D array.

I'm calling my R script with the following args:

```
Rscript myscript.R "1,5" "a,b,c,,e,f,g"
```

I have code which converts the first arg to a 1-D array as follows:

```
array1 <- lapply(strsplit(args[1], ','), as.character)[[1]]]
```

This results in

> [1] "1" "5"

I am happy with this, the following is where I need help:

I need code to convert my second arg to a 2-D array. Please help!
This is the desired output:

> [1] "a" "b" "c"
>   [2] "e" "f" "g"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a two-step splits?

```
strsplit(strsplit("a,b,c,,e,f,g", ",,")[[1]], ",")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "e" "f" "g"
```

If you prefer a matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit("a,b,c,,e,f,g", ",,")[[1]], ","))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "e"  "f"  "g"
```

Comment: thanks for the code. does this return a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns?

Comment: No. It is a list of length 2. You can convert it to a matrix with `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Comment: Just FYI. You don't need to use `lapply(..., as.character)` since `strsplit` return `character`.

Comment: OK I'll get rid of it. I only had it there because I found the answer on someone else's question. I'm new to R and kind of struggling..

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
v1 <- strsplit("a,b,c,,e,f,g", ",")[[1]]
split(v1[v1!=''], cumsum(v1=='')[v1!=''])
#$`0`
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$`1`
#[1] "e" "f" "g"
```